# turn off firewall with powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall, windows-scripting

I'm working on a command in Powershell that will look at the firewall (Domain) name (Enabled) and depending on if it's True the command will set it to false switching it off locally for the workstation.

right now I have this:

```
if (((Get-NetFirewallProfile -profile Domain,Enabled) | where { $_.Enabled -eq $True } | Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain -Enabled False
```

This is not working for me, it's not even giving me an error so I can't work out what is missing, can anyone see my mistake?

The command will be used on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with `Get-NetFirewallProfile -profile Domain,Enabled`. The `-Profile` flag has only three possible variants: Domain, Public, and Private.

Comment: so are you saying get rid of -profile and just use: Get-NetFirewallProfile Domain,Enabled ?

Comment: ok I got it now, If ( (Get-NetFirewallProfile Domain).Enabled -eq "True" ) thanks for your help.